# Delete an alarm

Tags: android, alarm

I have an  application that allow multiple alarms to be set and it repeats those alarms every day and it is working fine.
My problem is when I delete an alarm that was set to be fired at 12:00 a.m. the next day it will be fired at 12:00 a.m even if it is deleted! Anyone know where the problem might be?

I'm using an SQLite to store, retrieve and delete the alarms.

This is part of the `AlarmManager` I'm giving every alarm a different request code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Daily_OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID_DAILY, (long)reminderId); 
    int Daily_requestCode = reminderId.intValue(); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Daily_requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

and I'm also doing the same way for the notification. I'm giving every notification a different request code.

Anyone know why the alarm is firing even if I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using different `requestId` value, the `AlarmManager` `cancel()` method only checks the `PendingIntent` that you specify is equal.  However, filter equality does not depend on your extra data according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29). So you have to cancel them all and then loop through your database to add them back (skipping the one(s) you are deleting).